# Can a string have a palindrome, is there any better way to do this?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I had a very interesting interview question today :

> Given a string, you have to determine whether that string could have a palindrome when permuted.

The following is the implementation I came up with. But is there a better solution ?

```js
function canBePalindrome(someStr) {

    if (typeof someStr !== "string") {
      throw new Error("Expecting argument to be a string !");
    }

    if (someStr.length == 1) return someStr;
    var canBePalin = false;
    var _chunks = someStr.split("");
    var _length = _chunks.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j < _length; j++) {
        var temp_char = _chunks[i];
        _chunks[i] = _chunks[j];
        _chunks[j] = temp_char;

        if (isPalindrome(_chunks.join(""))) return true;

      }
    }
    return canBePalin;

  } //End of canBePalindrome


function isPalindrome(someStr) {
    //console.log("Checking for:"+someStr);
    var original = someStr.split("");
    return someStr === original.reverse().join("");
  } //End of isPalindrome

canBePalindrome("mdadm");
```

This wouldn't be a possible duplicate because, i'm not checking if it is palindrome directly, but permuting and checking it.

Comment: I think a better way would be to count the frequency of letters. Then, each letters frequency should be even. There can be one or zero letter with frequency 1.

Comment: So, what you are doing is actually permuting the string and checking for palindrome, I would love to see if this can be done in some intelligent way.

Comment: By the way, this is a very brute force way to do it. They would have hoped you already knew that there is an easier way. Now you know

Comment: Please clarify that we are comparing a string to itself. Some of the solutions assume two separate strings, but that seems an entirely different problem.

Comment: @Roberto It's clear the question asks for a way to check if there exists a permutation which is a palindrome. Not whether there exists a permutation which transforms a string to another one. That 2nd problem is not related to palindromes at all.

Comment: Most of the solutions look great, but when I test them they don't seem to work. Yet, perhaps my tests are incorrect. Can you provide some test values which would prove or disprove a solution, i.e., input and expected output?

Answer (score 6):

Keep a map of characters, count them, and see if the count is even for all characters, if it is, a palindrome can be created

```
function canBePalindrome(someStr) {
    var map = {};
    var arr = someStr.split('');

    arr.forEach(function(s) {
        s in map ? map[s]++ : map[s] = 1;
    });

    var len = Object.keys(map).filter(function(o) {
        return map[o] % 2;
    }).length;

    return arr.length % 2 ? len === 1 : len === 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3051syqh/1/)

A "golfed" version of the above would be

```
function canBePalindrome(someStr) {
    return (function(m, a, l) {
        a.forEach(function(s) { s in m ? m[s]++ : m[s] = 1 });  
        l = Object.keys(m).filter(function(o) { return m[o] % 2 }).length;
        return a.length % 2 ? l === 1 : l === 0;
    })({}, someStr.split(''));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If all the letters in a string have an even count,  except for at most one, you can always reorganize them into a palindrome. My solution is a little longer than others because I tried to minimize performance overhead of loops with functions and unnecessary array creation.

```
aaaabbbb => aabbbbaa
aaaabbbbc => aabbcbbaa


function isPalindromable(str) {
    var map = getCharCount(str);
    var nonPairs = 0;
    for (var char in charMap) {
        if (charMap[char] % 2 != 0)
            nonPairs++;
        if (nonPairs > 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function getCharCount(str) {
    // Number of times each string appeared
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var ch = str.charAt(i);
        map[ch] = ++map[ch] || 1;
    }
    return map;
}
```

If you like one liners (not as fast, but kind of elegant)

```
function isPalindromable(str) {
    var charMap = getCharCountMap(str);
    return Object.keys(charMap).filter(char => charMap[char] %2 > 0).length <= 1;
}

function getCharCountMap(str) {
    return str.split('').reduce((prev, cur) => (prev[cur] = ++prev[cur] || 1, prev) , {})
}
```

**Performance Edit**

I benchmarked the three solutions. Mine was the slowest when the strings were short, and fastest for longer strings. However, a friend at work came up with a solution that ends up being fastest, maybe because it only has one loop but doesn't need to sort. http://jsperf.com/can-string-be-made-into-palindrome/2

```
function canBePalindromeReplace(string) {
    var oddCount = 0;

    while(string.length > 0) {
        var char = string.charAt(0);
        var stringLength = string.length;
        string = string.replace(new RegExp(char, 'g'), '');
        var diff = stringLength - string.length;
        if((diff % 2) != 0) {
            oddCount++;
            if(oddCount > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi juan, your solution is  very much readable, and faster too. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: "except for one" = "except for at most one"

Answer (score 1):

Solution using sort and stack:

```
function canBePalindrome(someStr) {
    var stack = [];
    someStr.split('').sort().forEach(function(ch) {
        stack[stack.length - 1] === ch ? stack.pop() : stack.push(ch);
    });
    return stack.length < 2;
}
```

Comment: Note sorting is `n log n`, but this problem can be solved linearly.

Comment: @Oriol that's right, this is not the most optimal solution, but it is relatively simple

Answer (score 0):

One nice trick is to see the following properties of a palindrome:

- When the size of the string is pair, then all the chars should appear a pair number of times.
- When the size of the string is odd, then all the chars **but one** should appear a pair number of times.

With this info you can write an algorithm for counting the times every possible char appear in the string, then see if complies with the previous properties. This algorithm should have `O(N + M)` time complexity, where N is the size of the string and M is the amount of possible chars that may appear in your string. For example, if the string only has ASCII chars, then has `O(N + 255)` time complexity. The space complexity is of `O(N + M)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to create an array of length 26, `arr[26]`. One for each letter. Then go through the string increasing the frequency of each letter as they occur.

Once done, go through that `arr[]` and check if all the frequencies are even or not. There is room for just one character with odd frequency, that one we can put in the middle of the palindrome.

If all frequencies are even, then it can be organized as a palindrome.

Otherwise not.

---

The algorithm should look something like this

```
str[] holding the string;
create arr[26] and intialize with 0;

for char in str:
    arr[char]++  //char should be mapped to its index properly
                 // like a = 0, b = 1 and so on

no_of_odd_char = 0
for freq in arr:
    if(freq % 2 == 1)
        if(no_of_odd_char == 1)
            print "cannot be palindrome"
            exit()
        else if(no_of_odd_char == 0)
            no_of_odd_char = 1

print "can be palindrome"
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists a permutation of the string which is palindrome iff the number of characters which appear an odd number of times is 0 or 1.

```
function canBePalindrome(str) {
  var isOdd = Object.create(null),
      numOdd = 0;
  for(let ch of str)
    numOdd += (isOdd[ch] = !isOdd[ch]) * 2 - 1;
  return numOdd <= 1;
}
```

You can iterate with `for(var i=0; i<str.length; ++i)` to support pre-ES6 implementations, but that won't work properly if the string contains unicode code points beyond the first 16 bits of the code point range.